# how to improve page speed insight google

Tags: google-analytics, pagespeed

I am getting

> Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>
> https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js (15 minutes)
>
> http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

How to deal with it so it does not appear in pagespeed.insights results?

Comment: I think there is an embedded YouTube video in your page. That could be responsible for that script. Remove it or use another video platform.

Comment: You can't affect those URLs. Consider them false positives.